# mongoose dynamically attaching schema to validate against on the fly

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'd like to dynamically attach a schema to a particular field, based on some business logic in `schema.pre('save',function(..){...})`. How to do this, if at all possible?

Some (simplified) schemas and background:

```
var fact= new Schema({  
    name: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: false }}
    ,value: {type:  {}, required: true}  
    ,moreinfodesc: { type: String, required: false} 
    ,createddate : { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now, select: false } }
}, { collection: 'Fact' } );

var factSchema= new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true }}
    , valueType: { type: {}, required: true}                                        
    ,isMulti: {type: Boolean, required: true }

    //ACL-stuff
    ,directChangeRoles: {type: [String]} //i.e: [super, admin,owner]
    ,suggestChangeRoles: {type: [String]} //ie: [editor]
    ,enum: {type: [{}]} 
    ,mixins: {type: [String]} 
}, { collection: 'FactSchema' });
```

This is a simplified structure to allow "facts' of a particular 'entity' to be edited.

```
e.g: entityA.facts=[fact]
```

As can be seen from the schema's `fact.value` can have any type as far as mongoose is concerned. I however, want to constrain it at runtime to the schema as defined in 
`FactSchema.valueType` (a String containing "Boolean", "String" or something more complex as "[Tag]") . This might all seem cumbersome, but this is the way i'd like to go for several reasons.

So let's say that for a particular fact with `fact.name=tags` I want to assign  `fact.value` the type `[Tag]` at runtime. For this I would have setup a `Tag`-schema with validation like usual and have `fact.value` validate against it.

I was thinking of somehow "attaching" the `[Tag]`-schema to `fact.value` in `fact.pre('save',function(..){.. //validation here })` and hope validation would magically happen as if `fact.value`was assigned the type `[Tag]` at design-time instead of run-time.

Finally the question: I've got no idea if it's possible to do that 'attach' and if so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"attaching" at run time isn't possible but you can add a custom validator to your path and base its logic on current document state:

https://gist.github.com/2789681

Comment: Thanks Aaron, Mongoose is great stuff!.. In the meantime I've found a solution with using Mongoose's 'on-the-fly' schema's. I'm calling something like `fact.set('value', vals, multivalued?[onTheFlySchema]:onTheFlySchema);` just before calling `fact.save`. This works great, including all validation, hooks set-up on the `onTheFlySchema`. Suggestion: You might want to advertise the 'on-the-fly' schema's a bit more, they rock! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [mongoose discriminators](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html)
And if needed, you can alter the validation at runtime with:

```
YourModelName.schema.path('your_field_name').required(false);
```